# Problem in table migration that have foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I want to connect the state_id field of the 'users' table with a foreign key to the ID of the 'states' table, but it gives an error during the migration , I tried many solutions but the problem was not solved. I am using Laravel 9:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `digidb_final`.`companies` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `companies` add constraint `companies_state_id_foreign` foreign key (`state_id`) references `states` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at E:\Projects\DigiTork-Final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

  1   E:\Projects\DigiTork-Final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:544
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `digidb_final`.`companies` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   E:\Projects\DigiTork-Final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:544
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Users table :

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('NationalCode')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->string('Dateofbirth')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('gender')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_id');
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('banknumber')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

States table :

```
Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->boolean('active');
        });
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha, there is no Live Synaxt to run on. It runs with framework help

Comment: where is the `companies` migration? since that is the table the error is talking about

Answer (score 2):

Laravel comes with `users` migration by default which means it will place very first. Migration executes in FIFO (First In, First Out) method. So `users` migration will run at the beginning.

So at the time, `user` migration doesn't know any table exits.(ex: `states`)

> **Short and sweet: Before creating `foreign_key` constraint, create that table first**.

---

To overcome this issue:

1. Move all the `foreign key` declarations to the new schema.
2. Move the independent schemas to the top by renaming the migration file (Laravel uses timestamps to migrate schemas.)

If I need to run the project migration first:

[image]

[image]